# How to delete an incorrect url and/or site

Tags: google-search, url

I'm a total noob with a problem I can't seem to find an answer for, and another user suggested I try here. When I first created my site (`https://example.com`) using my domain host's (WPX) WordPress setup wizard, I made several beginner mistakes, and ended up deleting my initial attempt using the WP Reset plugin, deleting the initial content (I thought), and starting over.

On my first try, I didn't include the "s" in the WordPress or Site Address URL when configuring the new site. I have since corrected that error, but Google search still only shows the previous unsecured url (`http://example.com`). So--accessing my site through WP takes me to the dashboard for the correct and secure site (https://), but Google search only lists the unsecured version I thought I'd deleted (http://)

I investigated the "Removals" section on Google Search Console, but was hesitant to use it on the unsecured site as the "Temporary Removals" request states "All URL variations (www/non-www and http/https) will be affected," and I didn't want to accidentally affect the new secured site along with the unsecured one.

I don't even know where to begin--I've poked around the WP dashboard and tried to find the orphan page or url, but no luck. Is there a way to delete the unsecured url and page from WP and Google? Or make sure that Google only lists the secured site? Any assistance suitable for a struggling noob with no understanding of what he's doing would be most appreciated! Thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't know how to do it with WP or on WPX (I'm unfamiliar with both), but there should be an easy way to do two things. One is to have 301 redirects from the http versions to the https versions. The other is to add canonical URLs to the pages. Either would cause Google to drop the non-secure version next time it crawls it.